# Coding capital sigma notation

Tags: c, recursion, updown

I cannot find a way to code the following formula. My goal is to have a single function into which I can input the values. The context of this calculation is to return the number of possible upDown permutations of n-numbers. Without using bruteforce and checking each permutation, i can simply compute this sum:
[image: formula]
My code at the moment is this:

```
int e(int i, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return (0);
    else
        return (combinations(n, i)*e(n, i)*e(n, n-i));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n, sum = 0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + combinations(n, i)*e(n, i)*e(n, n-i);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: What is combinari?

Comment: @DerekBrown, a typo, fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Same question though- what is combinations?

Comment: Combinations as we know them in the mathematical meaning, i just didn't include the function for it. (n!/(k!(n-k)!))

Comment: My suggestion would be to rewrite this without recursion.  Recursion is inefficient, as it requires recalculating an entire tree of values.

Comment: Use a `for` loop to do the sum.,   Also the formula defines E_n+1, not E_n

Comment: Note that a 32-bit `int` can only store up to `12!`; `13!` is too big to fit.  A 64-bit `long long` can only store up to `20!`; `21!` is too big to fit.  You'll need to review your computations to ensure you avoid overflow.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, My input limit is 11, so not such problems should occur.

Comment: If you only need factorials to 11, use a precomputed table with the 11 possible values.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i'm asked to compute those numbers, not to hardcode them.

Comment: Shrug: that's not the way you'd do it in real life if the range was only to 11.  If the range was bigger, you might still use precomputed values, but they'd be stored in an array of `double` values since you rapidly run out of room in any integer type.  However, if the instructions are "thou shalt", then you better had do as instructed.  Just remember that the instructions may not be the best solution in the 'real world' (if anything on a computer is 'real').